# jquery-git.js:3369 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Error in Highcharts : Below is the code

```
Highcharts.Color.prototype.parsers.push({
    regex: /^[a-z]+$/,
    parse: function (result) {
        var rgb = new RGBColor(result[0]);
        if (rgb.ok) {
            return [rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b, 1]; // returns rgba to Highcharts
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, it's pretty explicit : `Highcharts.Color.prototype.parsers` is undefined. Where did you get this code? In Highchart's documentation?

Comment: As in the above comment - parsers doesn't exist in the Highcharts.Color prototype. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/avkr39ms/ Could you explain what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes , I found this in Highcharts Docs (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) , the sample code : (https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/zy1epj3o/)

Comment: But could you explain why are you using to push something in to the Highcharts.Color.prototype.parsers which doesn't exist? Why parsers? This variable/object/array doesn't exist in the Highcharts.Color.prototype.

Comment: Thanks for your concern . I want linear gradient in the highcharts  , And i think it was an issue from browser.